Elegant way to write $g(f(x))$
I've a very ugly expression:
$$
\frac{d^2 g(f(x))}{d (f(x))^2} \, \left( \frac{d f(x)}{dx} \right)^2 + \frac{d g(f(x))}{d f(x)} \,
\frac{d \left( \frac{df(x)}{dx} \right)}{d f(x)} \, \frac{d f(x)}{dx}
$$
I'm looking for a way to rewrite it in an elegant way without losing any information about the dependencies $g(f)$ and $f(x)$.
$$
\frac{d^2 g\circ f(x)}{d (f(x))^2} \, \left( \frac{d f(x)}{dx} \right)^2 + \frac{d g(f(x))}{d f(x)} \,
\frac{d \left( \frac{df(x)}{dx} \right)}{d f(x)} \, \frac{d f(x)}{dx}
$$

Is the notation $g\circ f(x)$ (g\circ f(x)) elegant enough?

@J.G. see the edit please. I Tried to use that notation and the result is a bit confused.

This is where Leibnizian notation shows its true colours and becomes inappropriate, maybe. A very common thing for people to do is to write "$u=f(x)$" and then we get to say stuff like $d^2g/du^2$ etc. this has its conceptual uses, but mathematically I'm not a fan

would dg/d(f(x)=a and d/dx=b work? ie $a(a(f(x)))[b(f(x))]^2+a(f(x))a(b(f(x)b(f(x))$. I''m not sure if that's kosher. (Here, I've been a bit lackadaisial in defining a, but something more concrete could be used)

I think $\frac{dg}{d(f(x)}=a(m)$ and $\frac{d}{dx}=b(m)$ would be more like it. Not sure.

What about writing what you're differentiating towards as a subscript, i.e., $f_x = \frac{df(x)}{dx}$. We would have $(g \circ f){ff} f_x^2 + g_f (f{x})_f f_x$.

Does "$\dfrac{d^{2}g(f(x))}{d(f(x))^{2}}$" (which looks like "$g$ viewed as a function of $f(x)$ differentiated twice with respect to $f(x)$" mean something other than $g''(f(x))$...? <> If not it appears you have $$g''(f(x)) f'(x)^{2} + g'(f(x))f'(f(x)) f'(x).$$ If so, do all the $g$s really denote the same function, or are some of them $g\circ f$? And can you explain how the expression in the question arises?

@AndrewD.Hwang it arises from the analysis of a compass gait model. All the $g$s are composite functions.

@Noud I like your writing, has it a name or do you invented it?

@FedericaGuidotti, the notation is called partial derivatives, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_for_differentiation#Partial_derivatives. It is mostly used, as the name would suspect, in partial differential equations.
